# Why is my Output rounding up my decimal number? Should I be using Decimal or something else?

Tags: c#, wpf, floating-point, double, decimal

C# Amateur here;

I'm creating a basic 'Quote Calculator', ItemQuantity * ItemCost.
I want the quantity to be whole numbers (1,2,3,4,5, etc), and cost can be either whole numbers or have decimal places (1, 2, 3.45, 6.2).

Everything is working in my WPF application, however, the TextBlock I am using to output the sum of `itemQuantity * itemCost` is showing a rounded integer.

Obviously, I'd like it to be accurate to two decimal places, but currently it rounds the figure up. What am I doing incorrectly?

```
List<Items> quoteList = new List<Items>();

 public void button_itemadd_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        quoteList.Add(new Items()
        {
            itemName = input_itemdesc.Text,
            itemQuantity = Convert.ToInt32(input_itemquantity.Text),
            itemCost = Convert.ToDecimal(input_itemcost.Text)

        });

        dataGridView1.ItemsSource = "";
        dataGridView1.ItemsSource = quoteList;
        updateQuote();
    }

    public void updateQuote()
    {
        decimal costTotal = 0;

            for (int i = 0; i < quoteList.Count; i++)
        {
            costTotal += (Convert.ToInt32(quoteList[i].itemCost) * Convert.ToDecimal(quoteList[i].itemQuantity));
        }
// output_quotecost is the TextBlock
        output_quotecost.Text = costTotal.ToString();
    }
}


class Items
{
    public string itemName { get; set; }
    public int itemQuantity { get; set; }
    public decimal itemCost { get; set; }
}
```

[image: Image of Program running]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like you mixed up the Convert methods on:

```
costTotal += (Convert.ToInt32(quoteList[i].itemCost) *
              Convert.ToDecimal(quoteList[i].itemQuantity));
```

Instead, it should be:

```
costTotal += (Convert.ToDecimal(quoteList[i].itemCost) *
              Convert.ToInt32(quoteList[i].itemQuantity));
```

You have to replace `.ToInt32` with `.ToDeciaml` in order to get the right output.